# Existence of splitting field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, splitting-field

Consider this theorem on existence of splitting field;
Let $F$ be a field and let $f(x)$ be a non-constant element of $F[x].$ Then there exists a splitting field $E$ for $f(x)$ over $F$.
In proving this theorem we use induction step on deg of $f(x)$ . If deg$f(x)$=1, then $f(x)$ is linear. so how when $f(x)$ is linear this theorem is true.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Prove that if $f\in F[x]$ is linear, then the splitting field of $f$ is $F$ itself.

Comment: (Actually, depending on the formalism you're using, this may literally be built into the definition. But in any case the statement is true under any reasonable definitions, so you should figure out why.)